# Value doesn't change

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class circle {

    private:
    double r;
    double const pi=3.14;

    public:

    circle(double rad){

        r=rad;

        }

    void periArea(){
        double p,s;

        p=2*pi*r;
        s=pi*pi*r;
        cout<<"\nS= "<<s<<endl;
        cout<<"\nP= "<<p<<endl;
        }

        friend void changeRad(circle circle, double newrad);
    };

    void changeRad(circle circle, double newrad){

        circle.r=newrad;

        }

int main()
{
    double inpr,newr;
    cout<<"input radius: ";
    cin>>inpr;
    circle c1(inpr);
    c1.periArea();
    cout<<"\ninput new radius: ";
    cin>>newr;
    changeRad(c1,newr);
    c1.periArea();
}
```

I've got this cpp code that has to define a class circle that calculates perimeter and area then using a friend function change the radius and calculate the area and perimeter again. However I get the same p and s values even after the change function.

Comment: Thats nice.   Do you intend to ***ask a question***?

Answer (score 6):

Crudely, you need to change your function to pass the circle *by reference*:

```
void changeRad(circle& circle, double newrad){
```

(Note the use of `&`). Otherwise a copy of the `circle` instance is passed to the function and any changes to that copy will not be reflected in the original.

**But**, the *normal* way of doing things is to arrange your code so that you use

```
c1.changeRad(newr);
```

at the call site.

Also, your use of a `double` to store pi to just 3 significant figures is pretty terrible. My favourite way is to use

```
const double PI = std::atan(1.0) * 4;
```

since the C++ standard does **not** define pi for you (`M_PI` is POSIX, not ISO!).

Comment: Calling a method *the normal way* sounds a bit strange to me. It is *the OOP way*. What is normal depends highly on the context, semantics, and style. There's nothing wrong with free functions acting on data-containing structs.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. This is for school it's in the assignment to declare pi as a double constanant and use a friend function outside of the class.

Comment: In which case, nick my value from the debugger, and hardcode it, or find one on the internet. But that is not the best thing to do since you might supply insufficient precision for the floating point double type on your platform. Note that supplying excess precision is never a problem as the compiler is required to discard excess digits after the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an object the type Circle by reference

```
friend void changeRad( circle &circle, double newrad);
                             ^^^
```

Take into account that though it is a valid declaration of a parameter when its name coincides with the name of the type nevertheless this can confuse the reader and the name of the parameter hides the name of the type. So it is better to rename the name of the parameter as for example

```
friend void changeRad( circle &c, double newrad);
                              ^^
```

Also it is better to make the function a non-static member of the class. For example

```
void changeRad( double newrad );
```